# Possible to ignore vs2005 custom build step failure?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, custom-build-step

I have a visual studio 2005 project with a custom build step that copies a library file to the target applications plugin directory. This works fine, but in the case where I have the target application open it fails, understandably.

The problem with this behaviour is it prevents my build from continuing, meaning I can't hit build, then grab a coffee, and expect the build to be complete when I get back.

My question is, can I set-up the project so that if the custom build step fails, the build will continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to handle the failure in the post build event. The following code fixes the issue:

```
copy $(TargetPath) "%programfiles%\mypath"
if errorlevel 1 goto BuildProcessFailed

goto BuildProcessOK
:BuildProcessFailed
echo BUILDPROCESS FAILED FOR PROJECT $(ProjectName)
goto ExitBuildProcess
:BuildProcessOK
echo BUILDPROCESS OK FOR PROJECT $(ProjectName)

:ExitBuildProcess
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the identical problem with an old project (VS2005 in Win7-32).
The build step with copy fails, as the target is set of any reason to read-only and hidden. Replacing copy with xcopy and some parameters helped me

Example:

Failing: `copy /Y C:\Dev\Projx\mydll.dll C:\Test\Projx\`

Working: `xcopy /Y /H /R C:\Dev\Projx\mydll.dll C:\Test\Projx\`